# Install SoC EDS and create .o file using Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, fpga, quartus, soc

I am a newbie. I have installed SoC EDS following the instructions below [SoCEDS and ARM Development Studio](https://www.rocketboards.org/foswiki/Documentation/SoCEDS?t=2020-04-17T22%3A46%3A12+00%3A00) and encountered the following [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frwfR.png): Has anyone experienced this error and managed to fix it?

I tried to create my first HelloWorld program and made a makefile like this [makefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSDY0.png)
I have installed all versions as 20.1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do not put link to snapshots. Copy and paste the command error messages in the question as text. It seems your new compiler in NOT in the PATH as seen by cygwin make.